# Read ETW TraceEvent and then write it back

Tags: windows, logging, trace, etw

I am writing an application that is processing windows ETW events.

My application creates a [logman](http://Audit%20record%20uploading%20--%20Idempotent?) session and configures the events to be written to `.etl` log files.

My application reads these `.etl` files, processes them, and then deletes the file.

**Problem: It is possible for this processing step to fail (see the code below).**

I need a mechanism to write-back the ETW events to an .etl file, to be processed later.

**How can I write a `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent` object (obtained via `DynamicTraceEventParser` callback delegate) *back* to disk (ideally, back to an `.etl` file?)**

**The solutions that come to mind:**

1. Write the failed events back to an `.etl` file -- this is the desired solution
2. Simply retain the entire event file in the event of any individual event processing errors, and let the successful records get processed twice. -- unfortunately our processing operation is not idempotent, so this will not work. (We can't allow records to be processed twice)
3. Write the event back to ETW event store-- I am open to this but would prefer option 1

**The (simplified) code:**

```
// For each .etl file
foreach (string fullFileName in eventFileNames)
{
    // Load the .etl file
    using (var source = new ETWTraceEventSource(fileFullName))
    {
        var parser = new DynamicTraceEventParser(source);
        parser.All += delegate (TraceEvent traceEvent)
        {
            bool proccessingSucceeded = ProcessEvent(traceEvent); // Processing code that can fail
            if (!proccessingSucceeded) 
            {
                // TODO: figure out a way to write this event back to disk (.etl file) to be processed later
            }
        };
        source.Process(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the TraceEvent Relogger sample: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-samples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing/TraceEvent/TraceEvent/50_SimpleFileRelogger.cs you can modify events or add new events to the event stream. I have used this to e.g. rename processes depending on their command line which works pretty well.

Comment: Would the downvoter kindly state their reason so that I can improve the question?